# Problem with dynamically created popup window

Tags: javascript

I am trying to dynamically create a popup form with some input fields when the user clicks some button; I am having a hard time to return the input values when the user closes the popup.

On the main form, I have something like:

```
function GetAnswers() {
    var answers=ShowPrompts();
    return answers; 
}

function ShowPrompts() {
    var answer="";
    var popup=window.open('','PopupForm'); 
    TextControl= popup.document.createElement("INPUT");
    TextControl.setAttribute("type", "text");
    TextControl.value="";
    TextControl.setAttribute("id", 'idInput1');
    popup.document.body.appendChild(TextControl);

    var ButtonControl = popup.document.createElement("button");
    var TextNode = popup.document.createTextNode("Save"); 
    ButtonControl.appendChild(TextNode); 
    ButtonControl.style.float="right";
    popup.document.body.appendChild(ButtonControl);

    ButtonControl.onclick = function(){
        InputControl=popup.document.getElementById('idInput1');
        answer=InputControl.value;  
    }

    return answer;
}
```

The problem is "answer" is only set when the user clicks the Save button; so when ShowPrompts is called, it just returns "".  How do I make the GetAnswers function to wait for the user to click on the Save button on the popup and get the answer value?

Comment: You need to use promises if you want to return the value from GetAnswers. Check this out: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptpromises.shtml the other way to go would be to use a callback, where showPrompts (and GetAnswers possibly) could have a function parameter that gets executed in `onClick`

Comment: Thank you.  Our company still uses older versions of IE, so we probably won't support javascript promises for a while.  Let me think about the call back approach.  I think the goal is to halt "return answers" in the GEtAnswers function until the user clicks the Save button.